# The syntax about "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()"

Tags: java

Environment : class

getExternalStorageDirectory() : method

getAbsolutePath() : method

---

I'm wondering about "class.method.method" syntax.

Could you please let me know what "method.method" syntax means?

Comment: Not entirely clear, but method calls may be chained in Java.  So `method1().method2()` means you are calling `method2()` on the return value of the call to `method1()`.  Post your full code for better results.

Comment: Thank you. The full statement is "String dirpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();”

Comment: Debug your code, and add a breakpoint on this line.  Then inspect each component of the call.  You will see exactly what is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [Javadocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) you will see that `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns a `File` Object and the `File` object has a method `getAbsolutePath()`

Instead of chaining these methods it could also be written as

```
File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = externalStorage.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I can understand after thinking for a while!

Comment: Now I understand! Thanks to you all!